# Improving paraffin wax adhesion to steel - surfactants and adhesion modifiers

Tags: surfactants, adhesion

**Context**

I use paraffin wax as a lubricant for my bicycle chain. It is a personal / DIY project. Essentially, wax is melted in a slow cooker and a bicycle chain is immersed in the melted wax.

There are commercial products where there are proprietary additives which are better performing. From what I understand, there are friction modifiers (WS2, PTFE etc) surfactants and adhesion modifiers.

I am already adding some very small amounts of WS2 and PTFE so I am happy with friction modifiers part.

**Question**

The commercial blends have small amounts of surfactants and adhesion additives. Can any of you suggest a few surfactants and adhesion additives which are available for non-commercial and non-bulk quantities?

Thank you!

Comment: Drop some high-grade motor oil in the paraffin mix and get all the needed extra ingredients.